# Problem with user permissions and groups in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying try to migrate the changes in my model but I get these errors:

```
The field main.CustomUser.groups was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.group', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.

The field main.CustomUser.user_permissions was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.permission', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.

The field main.CustomUser_groups.group was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.group', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.

The field main.CustomUser_user_permissions.permission was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.permission', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.
```

I have custom user model and use custom user creation, registration view instead of Django's basic models and views

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=127, unique=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username, email']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_nane(self):
        return self.username or self.email.split("@")[0]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

managers.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

views.py

```
class CustomUserCreationView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'custom_auth/register.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        login(self.request, user)


        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            return redirect('main:home')

        return super().form_valid(form)


class CustomUserLoginView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomUserLoginForm
    template_name = 'custom_auth/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        credentials = form.cleaned_data

        user = authenticate(username=credentials['username'], email=credentials['email'],
                            password=credentials['password'])

        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('main:home')
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Wrong credentials\
                                        please try again')
            return redirect('custom_auth:login')


def LogoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse_lazy('main:home'))
```

And here are the errors that I am getting:

```
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/vehicle_rental/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/vehicle_rental/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 302, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 566, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aqshinkerimov/PycharmProjects/VehicleRental_application/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 637, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field main.CustomUser.groups was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.group', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.
The field main.CustomUser.user_permissions was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.permission', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.
The field main.CustomUser_groups.group was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.group', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.
The field main.CustomUser_user_permissions.permission was declared with a lazy reference to 'custom_auth.permission', but app 'custom_auth' isn't installed.
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: I did add the error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show the INSTALLED_APPS setting in your `settings.py`